# How to output DateTime array elements where DateTime is greater than

Tags: c#

I have two arrays, `UserActivity` and `UserDateTime`. User Activity array holds the activities of what the user is doing and the `UserDateTime` holds the DateTime of the said activity. I cannot find a solution where I can output the DateTime where it's greater than such Date/Time whilst printing out the user activity.

For example:

```
[UserDateTime]      [UserActivity]
02/02/2018 02:20    User logs on
05/02/2018 15:20    User visits page
20/02/2018 16:10    User goes here
21/02/2018 12:00    User logs off
21/02/2018 13:00    User logs on
21/02/2018 15:00    User visits here
```

The Date and time has its own array (`UserDateTime`) while the users' activity is in the array `UserActivity`'.
etc.

My problem is that I can't programmatically output where the DateTime is greater than 20/02/2019 and the User Activity is linked to the date/time.

My code is followed:

```cs
string[] UserActivity = File.ReadAllLines(@"useractivityfile");
string[] UserDateTime = File.ReadAllLines(@"userdatetimesfile");
DateTime greaterthanthis = new DateTime(2018, 2, 20);
for (int i = 0; i < UserActivity.Length; i++)
{
  if (DateTime.ParseExact(UserDT[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > greaterthanthis)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(UserDT[i].Where(x >= greaterthanthis????); //very stuck on this part
    //Also want to link the useractivity so Console.WriteLine(UserDT[i] + UserDT[i])
  }
}
```

I've been overthinking and overcomplicating this code all week (stressed). Thank you for your help.

Comment: `(DateTime.ParseExact(UserDT[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture > greaterthanthis)` 2 open `(` only one closing `)`

Comment: May we have example for both file more clearly? The exemple look like he hold both info.In order to clearly see the format of the file.

Comment: What is the content of both files ?

Comment: How do you know what lines goest to what activity? Do you use the index(lines number)? If you have controle over this log i would suggest that date and activity are store together. So you don't go crazy later.

Comment: @PablonotPicasso The contents of the file are both displayed in the 2 arrays (UserDateTime and UserActivity).

Comment: @xdtTransform By creating a for loop to reiterate through both arrays and outputting to console. And unfortunately the log was given to me thus trying to do the best out of it.

Comment: You have this DateTime greaterthanthis = new DateTime(2018, 2, 20); Don't you want 2019 instead of 2018

Comment: If you link activities with dates by line number than use try `Console.WriteLine(UserDT[i].ToString() + " : " + UserActivity[i]);` This will print date and activity for this date.

Comment: @PedroBrito I've edited that now, thank you! I want it for greater than 2018 not 2019. My mistake.

Comment: @PablonotPicasso I can do that yes, done before. Though I cannot get output for UserDT to be greater than a specific date. The problem is that even on a conditional, it would only reiterate through the array from the beginning and avoiding outputting the greater than date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pls. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

```
        string[] UserActivity = File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
        string[] UserDateTime = File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
        DateTime greaterthanthis = new DateTime(2018, 2, 20);
        for (int i = 0; i < UserActivity.Length; i++)
        {
            if (DateTime.ParseExact(UserDateTime[i], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > greaterthanthis)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(UserDateTime[i].ToString() + " : " + UserActivity[i]);
            }
         }
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. I've spent almost 4 days trying to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of typo in your code:

> for (int i = 0; **x** < UserActivity.Length; i++)
>   =>   for (int i = 0; **i** < UserActivity.Length; i++)
>
> if (DateTime.ParseExact(UserDT[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture > greaterthanthis **)** )
>   => if (DateTime.ParseExact(UserDT[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture **)** > greaterthanthis)

The ParseExact format match your 1rst version but doesn't match your file format

The easier step will be to get away from those files and make a reasonable object out of it:

```
public class Logs
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you example bothe file don't have the same number of lines...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public class Logs
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var UserDateTime_TEXT = @"02/02/2018 02:20    
05/02/2018 15:20    
21/02/2018 12:00    
21/02/2018 13:00    
21/02/2018 15:00  ";  
    var UserActivity_TEXT = @"User logs on
User visits page
User goes here
User logs off
User logs on
User visits here";


    //Equivalent to ReadAllLines
    string[] UserDateTime = UserDateTime_TEXT.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] UserActivity = UserActivity_TEXT.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // ps in your exemple there is more activity than date time... 
    // UserDateTime.Length != UserActivity.Length !!!!!!!!!!!           

    var data = new List<Logs>();
    //in your code you had `x < UserActivity.Length`, what is x?
    for (int i = 0; i < UserDateTime.Length; i++)
    {
        var splitValues =  UserActivity[i].Split(' ');
        var temp =
                new Logs
                {
                    Date = DateTime.ParseExact(UserDateTime[i].Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Name = splitValues[0], // No space in username. 
                    Activity = string.Join(" ", splitValues.Skip(1))
                };
        data.Add(temp);         
    }

    //filter
    var greaterThanThis = new DateTime(2018, 2, 20);

    var result = data.Where(x=> x.Date > greaterThanThis);

    foreach(var entry in data){
        Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Name} did  {entry.Activity} at {entry.Date}");
    }

}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fa8H2Z)

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help! Much appreciated and learnt from it:)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, your code looks like a complete mess. Brackets were wrong, variable names were wrong, LINQ query was wrong as well.
Use this as a start:

```
string[] UserActivity = File.ReadAllLines(@"useractivityfile");
string[] UserDateTime = File.ReadAllLines(@"userdatetimesfile");
DateTime greaterthanthis = new DateTime(2019, 1, 12);
for (int i = 0; i < UserActivity.Length; i++)
{
  if (DateTime.ParseExact(UserDateTime[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > greaterthanthis)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(UserDateTime[i]);
    //Also want to link the useractivity so Console.WriteLine(UserDT[i] + UserDT[i])
  }
}
```

If you want a LINQ query, try this:

```
UserDateTime.Where(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > greaterthanthis).ToList().ForEach(dt => Console.WriteLine(dt));
```

But I recommend to stay with the upper code for an easier overview and debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm still at a very beginner stage of C# but thanks for your constructive feedback.